# How to get clicked portion coordinates in pdf with ng2-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, typescript, html2canvas, pdf.js, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I have a requirement to get a position of an element from the pdf . Currently, I am using ng2pdf viewer.

stackblitz: when I clicked on the image inside pdf I need the coordinates of the clicked element.

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-pdf-viewer
```

How to do this by using this library in angular or recommended for any other library also good.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have to do the same thing, and I don't know if there's a library that has this functionality.

The naive approach is to make a Canvas above the PDF visualizator and then get the cursor position of it (in relation to the canvas), then you can make a method to do the conversion that you are showing.

Comment: yes i did by using renderer 2  to get the native element and get the co-ordinates by mouse click